# como mudar o subtitulo da pagina com a escolha de um select

Tags: javascript, html5, select

Galera é bem simples,
tenho um formulário que pode servir para vários serviços. Eu preciso que o subtítulo da pagina se altere conforme for a escolha (em um select) do serviço.

estou usando o seguinte um pouco do código

```
<header class="jumbotron">
    <h1>
        <img src="img/logo.png">
    </h1>
    <h2>Pedido de Serviço de importação</h2>
    <h3><h3> //AQUI FICARIA O SUBTITULO DA PAGINA
</header>

<fieldset class="campos">
<legend>Dados do serviço</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="servico">Tipo de serviço</label>
<select name="servico" class="form-control" id="servico">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="DESOVA DIRETA C/ DEVOLUÇÃO DE VAZIO">DESOVA DIRETA C/ DEVOLUÇÃO DE VAZIO</option>
<option value="DESOVA DIRETA">DESOVA DIRETA</option>
<option value="DESPALETIZAÇÃO">DESPALETIZAÇÃO</option>
<option value="ETIQUETAGEM">ETIQUETAGEM</option>
<option value="FOTOS">FOTOS</option>
<option value="MONITORAMENTO DE TOMADA ELETRICA">MONITORAMENTO DE TOMADA ELETRICA</option>
<option value="OVAÇÃO ">OVAÇÃO </option>
<option value="PALETIZAÇÃO">PALETIZAÇÃO</option>
<option value="PESAGEM DE VOLUMES">PESAGEM DE VOLUMES</option>
<option value="POSICIONAMENTO DE CARGA">POSICIONAMENTO DE CARGA</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 1):

Veja se isso te ajuda:

```js
servico.onchange = function() {
  subtitulo.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

```html
<header class="jumbotron">
    <h1>
        <img src="img/logo.png">
    </h1>
    <h2>Pedido de Serviço de importação</h2>
    <h3 id="subtitulo"><h3>
</header>

<fieldset class="campos">
<legend>Dados do serviço</legend>
<div class="form-group">
<label for="servico">Tipo de serviço</label>
<select name="servico" class="form-control" id="servico">
<option value=""></option>
<option value="DESOVA DIRETA C/ DEVOLUÇÃO DE VAZIO">DESOVA DIRETA C/ DEVOLUÇÃO DE VAZIO</option>
<option value="DESOVA DIRETA">DESOVA DIRETA</option>
<option value="DESPALETIZAÇÃO">DESPALETIZAÇÃO</option>
<option value="ETIQUETAGEM">ETIQUETAGEM</option>
<option value="FOTOS">FOTOS</option>
<option value="MONITORAMENTO DE TOMADA ELETRICA">MONITORAMENTO DE TOMADA ELETRICA</option>
<option value="OVAÇÃO ">OVAÇÃO </option>
<option value="PALETIZAÇÃO">PALETIZAÇÃO</option>
<option value="PESAGEM DE VOLUMES">PESAGEM DE VOLUMES</option>
<option value="POSICIONAMENTO DE CARGA">POSICIONAMENTO DE CARGA</option>
</select>
```

Primeiro eu coloquei um id no seu `h3` (subtitulo):

```
<h3 id="subtitulo"><h3>
```

Depois eu atribui uma função para o evento `onchange` do seu `select`:

```
servico.onchange = function() {
    subtitulo.innerHTML = this.value;
}
```

Toda vez que o `select` for atualizado ele vai pegar o valor e jogar dentro do elemento com `id=subtitulo`.

Comment: tentei usar desse jeito não deu certo não. Mas o camarada ali em cima já me deu o help. Obrigada pela atenção amigo

Answer (score 1):

Segue um javascript puro e simples para isso.
espero que ajude

```
   <header class="jumbotron">
        <h1>
            <img src="img/logo.png">
        </h1>
        <h2>Pedido de Serviço de importação</h2>
        <h3 id="subtitulo"><h3> //AQUI FICARIA O SUBTITULO DA PAGINA
    </header>

    <fieldset class="campos">
    <legend>Dados do serviço</legend>
    <div class="form-group">
    <label for="servico">Tipo de serviço</label>
    <select name="servico" class="form-control" id="servico" onchange="drop()">
    <option value=""></option>
    <option value="DESOVA DIRETA C/ DEVOLUÇÃO DE VAZIO">DESOVA DIRETA C/ DEVOLUÇÃO DE VAZIO</option>
    <option value="DESOVA DIRETA">DESOVA DIRETA</option>
    <option value="DESPALETIZAÇÃO">DESPALETIZAÇÃO</option>
    </select>

    <script>
    function drop(){
        document.getElementById("subtitulo").innerText = document.getElementById("servico").value;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: deu certo amigo. Muiitooo obrigada!!!

Comment: Legal tmj :) abs